# ListViewItems opens same Activity but with different content

Tags: android, android-listview, android-activity

I have a ListView that gets TutorialTitels  from the string file like so

```
public class tutorialActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tutorial);
        registerClickCallBack();
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.tutorialList);

        String tutorialTitle1 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial1_title);
        String tutorialTitle2 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial2_title);
        String tutorialTitle3 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial3_title);
        String tutorialTitle4 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial4_title);
        String tutorialTitle5 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial5_title);
        String tutorialTitle6 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial6_title);
        String tutorialTitle7 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial7_title);
        String tutorialTitle8 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial8_title);
        String tutorialTitle9 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial9_title);
        String tutorialTitle10 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial10_title);
        String tutorialTitle11 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial11_title);
        String tutorialTitle12 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial12_title);
        String tutorialTitle13 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial13_title);
        String tutorialTitle14 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial14_title);

        String[] values = new String[] { tutorialTitle1, tutorialTitle2, tutorialTitle3, tutorialTitle4, tutorialTitle5, tutorialTitle6, tutorialTitle7, tutorialTitle8, tutorialTitle9, tutorialTitle10, tutorialTitle11, tutorialTitle12, tutorialTitle13, tutorialTitle14};

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void registerClickCallBack() {
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.tutorialList);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked,int position, long id) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

When I click on a listViewItem then I'd like to open up an Activity that'll show the following things:

- The clicked TutorialTitel
- Tutorial content (This will also come from a string file, like so 
  `String tutorialContent1 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial1_content);`)
- Tutorial example ((This will also come from a string file, like so 
  `String tutorialExample1 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial1_example);`))

I already have an XML file like so

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tutorialTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/split"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="#38b34a"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />


            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/tutorialContent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:text=""/>


            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/tutorialExample"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:text=""/>


        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

The question: How do I pass the data to my activity corresponding to my clicked `ListviewItem`? should I do something like

```
if(position == 0){
//Send data through extra bundle
}
else if(position == 1){
//send data through extra bundle
}
```

But there should be a better way I think, but I don't know how exactly, because what if I'll getting 100 tutorials how should I manage a list long like that?
Can someone point me in the correct direction and what is the best approach to do this?

Comment: What about sqlite database? E.g. just one table: rowid, title, content, example. Then you could access your tutorials by id. First activity will display all your tutorial titles, and the second one will be detailed view. There is nice framework to work with database - "ORMlite" for android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a listener to `ListView` using `setOnItemClickListener();` this listener callback will give three parameter as  `onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)` in which position will give the position of the list item clicked.

so using this `position` you can use as `values[position]` and same for `tutorialContent` and `tutorialExample` and pass it in `intent` and start `Activity` with this intent having the selected item data

This is a Quick solution for your problem. But i will not recommend because the way you have implemented is not in the object oriented standard.

I recommend you to create a model class for `Tutorial`   with having member variable title, content, and example.

```
Class Tutorial{
    private String title;
    private String content;
    private string example;
}
```

and pass this object in the intent.

Comment: I'll be going for your method I think. But can you help me implement it please? I made a function `registerClickCallBack()` and I have implemented `onItemClick` But now I'm stuck, I don't know how to retrieve the clicked position. I have updated my question with the code snippet I'm talking about, you can find it in the first code block in TutorialActivity

Answer (score 0):

First keep your strings in an array file (array.xml). Then read them to an String array;

```
String [] myresources=resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.somelist);

    for(int i=0;i<NumberOfTutorials;i++){
        if(position==i){
            //send myresources[i];
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enum`. For example you can define `Tutorials` enum like this:

```
public enum Tutorials
{
    TUTORIAL_1(R.string.tutorial1_title, R.string.tutorial1_content, R.string.tutorial1_example),
    TUTORIAL_2(R.string.tutorial2_title, R.string.tutorial2_content, R.string.tutorial2_example),
    TUTORIAL_3(R.string.tutorial3_title, R.string.tutorial3_content, R.string.tutorial3_example);

    private int mTitleResourceId;
    private int mContentResourceId;
    private int mExampleResourceId;

    private Tutorials(int titleResourceId, int contentResourceId, int exampleResourceId)
    {
        mTitleResourceId = titleResourceId;
        mContentResourceId = contentResourceId;
        mExampleResourceId = exampleResourceId;
    }

    public int getTitleResourceId()
    {
        return mTitleResourceId;
    }

    public int getContentResourceId()
    {
        return mContentResourceId;
    }

    public int getExampleResourceId()
    {
        return mExampleResourceId;
    }
}
```

In this enum you can define 100 tutorials if you wish.
And then in your activity you can use it like this in generic way:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tutorial);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.tutorialList);

    List<String> titlesList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Tutorials tutorial: Tutorials.values())
    {
        titlesList.add(getResources().getString(tutorial.getTitleResourceId()));
    }
    String[] values = titlesList.toArray(new String[titlesList.size()]);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And finally on click item on the list you can easily retrieve the Tutorial enum by its string title and then you will have the tutorial content and and tutorial example for free.

Once you set this code, you will add tutorials only to `Tutorials` enum and that's it.

Hope it helps. Of course, using sqlite is also an option.